# Convert actual image to base64 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

We're using a Rest endpoint that returns an actual image like so:

`@image = RestClient.get('http://example.com/api/v1/scopes/12345/icon', headers).body`

And the response is something like:

```
�PNG

���
IHDR���������H�۱���PLTE������� ��/��>��M��\��j��y������������������������������������������5��J��c�����������������3��i��������������:��Z��z�����������C��e��������������.��V��~���������(��U����������@��r�����K��|����������
��B��w���������+��f����*����E��������O������������T�������<����������F����������b��1�܀�����0����?�� �֟��N��S���������L�������������W��������m������s��������;��l��k��%�ڑ�����o��n����4��������`�����_�����؊���ْ�����$�����"�ڜ�������ց��d��������������!�ڥ��g�����������x��I�����և����X���ن�����H��,�ۿ����������p��)�����#��������D��}����h��8�ݝ��������2�ܳ��[������'��t��9��q��a������]��������6��������{�����������������
��u����-��7��P�����A��^����������������������R����=��Y��Q��&�ڼ�����G��v���بxi���=�IDATx���a�����ݳm�����3�L
```

We want to Base64 encode this and display it on a View in our Rails app:

```
<%= image_tag(Base64.encode(@image)) %>
```

However it seems that the Base64 is expecting us to Open a file and pass that... e.g.

```
<%= image_tag(Base64.encode(File.open(@image).read)) %>
```

But this API returns the actual image...

Tried using `send_data` as well...

`Base64.encode64(send_data(RestClient.get('http://example.com/api/v1/scopes/12345/icon', headers).body, disposition: 'inline'))`

But then just sends the image to the browser and bypasses our view...

How can we Base64 encode and display this image on our View?

Comment: What is the output of `Base64.encode(@image)`. I suspect, that it encodes wrong text representation.
Or what class is `@image`?

Comment: @DonPaulie Well it becomes the stuff above encoded... but if we decode that we'd just be smashing that on the page... so how do we get that into an image tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting the binary data to base64 and passing that as data source isn't enough on its own. This would produce:

```
<img src="asdf...sdf==" />
```

Which isn't a valid source.

You have to create an [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```html
<%= image_tag("data:image/png;base64,#{Base64.encode64(@image)}") %>
```

This assumes your data has a MIME type of `image/png`. You could make this dynamic, but you have to extract the MIME type from the file or the extension somehow.

You might also be able to leave out the MIME type, since it's optional for data URIs. I'm not sure how the webbrowser would react to this though:

```html
<%= image_tag("data:;base64,#{Base64.encode64(@image)}") %>
```

You could also create a helper for this. The asset pipeline already has a helper [`asset_data_uri`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sprockets/4.0.0/Sprockets%2FContext:asset_data_uri). However since you fetch your images dynamically they are not part of the static server assets you might not be able to use it.

Comment: Note that the method to encode strings as Base64 is called [`Base64.encode64`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-encode64) (note the trailing `64` on the method name).